# How to call elasticsearch - ELK - API from elastalert?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastalert

This may not be right place to ask this question. But I could not find articles to do so.
I have below packages installed on CentOS.

```
Elasticsearch (I don't need it as I am trying to talk to ELK stack cluster using an API. I don't want ealsticsearch run locally on the box where I have elastalert.)
ISO8601 or Unix timestamped data
Python 2.6 or 2.7
pip, see requirements.txt
```

But, how do I make a call to an elastic search cluster using an API. I have API and a service account to do so.
Here is what, I am looking for.
Which file under elastalert-master/example_rules, should I modify?

I have tried changing config.yaml.example as well but that keeps calling auth py files and errors out.
I know that I don't have to auth anything as I have the API and service account.
I just have to use elastakert as a cron to do so.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with Python so let me try to answer with Python. I'm using module requests.

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

In [3]: url = 'http://es-server:9200/my_log*/_count'
In [4]: data = '''{
   ....:   "query": {
   ....:     "bool": {
   ....:       "must": [
   ....:         {
   ....:           "term": {
   ....:             "deployment": "testapp"
   ....:           }
   ....:         }
   ....:       ]
   ....:     }
   ....:   }
   ....: }'''

In [5]: resp = requests.get(url, auth = HTTPBasicAuth('esuser', 'espwd'), data = data)

In [6]: j = resp.json()

In [7]: j
Out[7]: 
{u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'successful': 185, u'total': 185},
 u'count': 2393083}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @felixc. But, I am not looking for a way to make an API call this way. This is similar to the way I can use SOAP or POSTMAN REST tools to query ELK stack. I am looking a way to use elastalert config files to make calls to ELK stack.